# unable to find exception on Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

i have a WEB API which is deployed on App Service and i have a API Management Instance which is pointed to that API.i am new to Azure so i want to test application insights analytics feature on it so i have write a action and throw exception on it.but the problem is exception is not showing on application insights at azure portal. any idea what's the issue ?

i can see the failure request with dependency and Request but can't fin exception check snap for more info

[image]

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see the exceptions via search or logs in azure portal.

1.See exceptions via search: Nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> click on the "Search" button, then select a proper time range and select "exception" only from the "Event types" dropdown -> then click on the exception from the result to see more details. The screenshot short is as below:

[image]

2.See exceptions via logs: Nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> click on the "Logs" button -> then click on the exceptions table, and specify a proper time range -> click run button. The screenshot is as below:

[image]